# How to use delimiter?

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile the following code, but I keep getting the ***cannot find symbol error***. The assignment requires the use of ***getInput*** method which ***requires no argument and return nothing as well***, its main funcion is to read the input and display it. So I was trying to change the scope of the scanner variable ***input*** and ***inputString*** so that whenever ***getInput*** is called, I dont have to pass them in to it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadKeyboardInput
{   
   public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static String inputString;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {     

      input.useDelimeter("\\n");

      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      getInput();
      System.out.print("Enter a float: ");
      getInput();
      System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
      getInput();      
   }
    public static void getInput()
    {                 
      inputString = input.next();
      System.out.println("You have entered: " + inputString + ".");
    }
}
```

Or if I bring the ***input.useDelimeter("\n");*** outside of the ***main*** scope, then I get another 2 errors  ***'identifier' expected*** and ***illegal start of type*** for this particular line. This altered code looks like above, except for :

```
   public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static input.useDelimeter("\\n");
   public static String inputString;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { ....
```

Comment: What's the symbol that can't be found?

Comment: The error looks like this:                              
error: cannot find symbol
      input.useDelimeter("\\n");
           ^
  symbol:   method useDelimeter(String)
  location: variable input of type Scanner
1 error

Answer (score 3):

You spelled `Delimiter` wrong, maybe? A `delimeter` would be something that measures the corned beef before it goes on your sandwich.

Comment: Omg .. problem solved.Thank you. I thought I corrected that but apparently I didn't.

Comment: It's always the silliest things. Glad this was it! :-)

Comment: If you get a chance, please mark this answer (or another, if it worked better for you) as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code segment doesn't seem to have a problem.

---

As for the suggested modification, you obviously misunderstand what it means to say `public static whatever`. You can only use that to declare variables and methods with class scope. You can't do anything else. If that's what you really want to do, put in a static initilalization block. Just put this:

```
static {
    input.useDelimiter("\\n");
}
```

Comment: I think I figured out where I messed up. Thank you though!
As for the Static thing you said, I'm not sure what you mean. My understanding is static simply means whatever comes after will be created before instantiation of the class right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `input.useDelimeter("\\n");` write `input.useDelimiter("\\n");`.
That should work for you.